# Automatically reopen an Android application when it gets closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am working on an android application in which I have to always run it on the phone (application sends sms). Sometimes other users close it.

I need to autolaunch my application whenever it gets closed.

Is it possible?

Comment: develop it as a service.

Comment: Use service or relaunch it in onDestroy event

Comment: No guarantee you will see onDestroy. Needs a service one way or the other.

Comment: this is a very bad practice that can easily get your app considered as malware. Code it as a service as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just prevent the application from being able to be closed via the back button by overriding `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {}
```

Now the user can't quit out of the app by pressing the back button.

**OR** to achieve what you initially wanted. Have this method...

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityName.class);
    startActivtiy(i);
}
```

That above code will start the activity when it is destroyed. I haven't tested it to see if it works though.

Comment: You can always quit with the home button and that cannot be overriden

Comment: @MarvinLabs Home, unlike back, doesn't usually cause the app to close. If it's able to be run in the background, it will.

Comment: Back does not necessarly close it either. The OS decides whether he needs to close it or not. Wanting an app to always be running is both a bad technical and UX decision. Background services are meant to cover these use cases.

Answer (score 0):

The OS decides whether he needs to destroy an application or not. Wanting an app to always be running is both a bad technical and UX decision.

Background services are meant to cover these use cases. Your UI may not necessarly be visible, but your service will register Broadcast receivers to get notified of events and eventually launch the app/show a notification.